# Apply a tag to a topic in a Google Group based on containing text

Tags: google-groups, google-groups-migration

I'd like to scan a Google Group (thats been created in Google Apps for Business) and add a 'tag' to all topics that match criteria (based on a containing text string).

For Example: I have a Google Group Collaborative Inbox that has 1000's of topics (as a result from an Exchange 2010 Shared Mailbox migration). I want a script to scan this group and if the subject or body has text matching a string then to assign it a specific tag.

Unlike mailbox to Gmail where folders are converted to labels, there is no option to convert a folder to a tag when moving mails from Exchange shared mailbox to a Google Group Collaborative Mailbox.

Any advise, links or help appreciated. I've researched and this post is the closest to my request which indicates its possible. https://gist.github.com/4072792

Many thanks